# ": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern when using " instead of ' in sed search pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to use a variable inside sed in a for loop. At first I though my problem was that I was using ' instead of " surounding my sed command but this also produces the same error. I am sure it is very easy to fix but I am unable to figure it out

the text i am trying to format looks like this

```
sharename:/path/to/share
```

for loop looks like this

```
for SERVERNAME in server1 server2; do
       sed -e "s|^|\\\\$SERVERNAME\\|"
done
```

this code returns this error

```
sed: 1: "s|^|\\server1\|
": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
sed: 1: "s|^|\\server2\|
": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
```

Comment: Try 8 and 4  backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @GrumpyCrouton

```
    for SERVERNAME in server1 server2; do
       sed -e "s|^|\\\\$SERVERNAME\\|"
    done
```